# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a small problem, I am modifying the tab structure of My Account in WooCommerce and I want to link 'Addresses' with 'Account details' and the problem occurs with 'Addresses' when I try to print the fields of that tab in 'Account Details' occurs:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach () in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ wp-content \ plugins \ woocommerce \ templates \ myaccount \ form-edit-address.php on line 34
```

And this is the error code:

```
<?php 
foreach ($address as $key => $field) { // **line 34**
woocommerce_form_field ($key, $field, wc_get_post_data_by_key ($key, $field ['value']));
}
?>
```

Do a var_dump where it throws NULL. Seeing all this, I tried to modify the function in class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php where I do not achieve my goal. I have thought that there is some limitation so that the array is only available in that template; I do not know if I'm right and what I found in wc-template-functions.php was:

```
function woocommerce_account_edit_address( $type ) {
        $type = wc_edit_address_i18n( sanitize_title( $type ), true );

        WC_Shortcode_My_Account::edit_address( $type );
    }
}
```

How can I print the array $address in a custom tab? Thanks!

**UPGRADE:**

One of my attempts is to include the file form-edit-address.php in form-edit-account.php

```
<?php
include("form-edit-address.php");
?>
```

Another attempt was to copy the contents of the form-edit-address.php file into the form-edit-account. Also try to place the global $ address and $ load-address variables without any effect:

```
public static function edit_address( $load_address = 'billing' ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        global $load_address;
        $load_address = sanitize_key( $load_address );
        $country      = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $load_address . '_country', true );

        if ( ! $country ) {
            $country = WC()->countries->get_base_country();
        }

        if ( 'billing' === $load_address ) {
            $allowed_countries = WC()->countries->get_allowed_countries();

            if ( ! array_key_exists( $country, $allowed_countries ) ) {
                $country = current( array_keys( $allowed_countries ) );
            }
        }

        if ( 'shipping' === $load_address ) {
            $allowed_countries = WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries();

            if ( ! array_key_exists( $country, $allowed_countries ) ) {
                $country = current( array_keys( $allowed_countries ) );
            }
        }

        global $address;

        $address = WC()->countries->get_address_fields( $country, $load_address . '_' );

        // Enqueue scripts.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-country-select' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-address-i18n' );

        // Prepare values.
        foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) {

            $value = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key, true );

            if ( ! $value ) {
                switch ( $key ) {
                    case 'billing_email':
                    case 'shipping_email':
                        $value = $current_user->user_email;
                        break;
                }
            }

            $address[ $key ]['value'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_field_value', $value, $key, $load_address );
        }

        wc_get_template(
            'myaccount/form-edit-address.php',
            array(
                'load_address' => $load_address,
                'address'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_address_to_edit', $address, $load_address ),
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Is there really a space between the `$` and the variable name in your code? If so, that's not legit. See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Updrade post, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would need to look at your code closer but I am guessing that the issues it the way you are typing your variables.

Try `$address` instead of `$ address`

Comment: This could not be the answer of the question, before this he has wrong syntax `<? php ` at the very start.

Comment: @Asif Very true but given the information that was provided it was the most likely answer that I could find

Comment: If more information is provided I will update my answer

Comment: Sorry, it was by translation. The variables are correctly, $ address, $ load-address, and so on ... Update the publication and place code that I modified